# How to remove/reduce noise from .wav audio file in python

Tags: python-3.x, audio, hex, speech-recognition, noise-reduction

I have a .wav audio file, I'm working on converting the audio to text. I need to reduce/remove noise to get more accurate result.

Please let me know how to go about it

```
import wave
import sys

import binascii

ip = wave.open('C:\\Users\\anagha\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\a1.wav', 'r')

op = wave.open('C:\\Users\\anagha\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\r_1.wav', 'w')
op.setparams(ip.getparams())

for i in range(ip.getnframes()):
iframes = ip.readframes(1)
amp = int(binascii.hexlify(iframes))
if amp > 32767:
    amp = 65535 - int(binascii.hexlify(iframes))#-ve
    print(amp)
else:
    amp = int(binascii.hexlify(iframes))#+ve
    print(amp)
if amp < 2000:
    #make it zero
    final_frame = '\x00\x00'
else:
    #Keep the frame 
    final_frame = iframe
op.writeframes(final_frame)
op.close()
ip.close()
```

getting error :

```
 ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'ffff'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to convert a non- number into int,

Perhaps, you meant.

```
    amp = int(len(binascii.hexlify(iframes)))
```

Answer (score 0):

While converting to int a hex string which is without leading '0x' specify the base manually. Like follows:

```
int(binascii.hexlify(iframes), 16)
```